# Инструмент проверки отображения сайта на iPhone?

Tags: html, css, ios

Поделитесь ссылочкамми на инструменты проверки отображения сайта на iPhone. Не важно, будет-ли это онлайн сервис или десктопная программа.

Почему я прошу поделиться ссылками? Все потому, что я не нашел в интернете реально имитировавших iPhone инструментов. В интернете полно "псевдо" имититаторов, например [responsinator](https://www.responsinator.com/), которые лишь ресайзят окно, но никак не имитируют отображение на реальном iPhone.

Проверяю инструменты на реальном iPhone 7 сестры, которая скоро уедет и наступит пушистый зверек...

Comment: Посмотрите `iPadian 2`, может поможет - Этот бесплатный симулятор iOS.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин установил, запустил, программа зависла. Переустановил 3 раза, смог войти, Safari не открывает ссылки. Кривое приложение какое-то... Да и iPhone не эмитировать.

Comment: Хорошие онлайн эмулятор, рекомендую! https://www.browserstack.com/responsive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужен идеальный инструмент для работы с мобильной версии сайта, вам нужен **http://mobiletest.me/**
Этот ресурс условно бесплатный, т.е вы имеете возможность без лимитов и без регистрации работать с 6 девайсами (*iPhone 5,HTC One,Nokia Lumia 920,Samsung Galaxy Y,Google Nexus 7,iPad mini*).Благодаря им вы можете протестировать адаптивную вёрстку для основных размеров(*320x568,360x640,460x768,603x966,768x1024*).

Если вам нужен именно эмулятор для разных моделей мобильных, необходимо зарегистрироваться и вы получите бесплатный месяц для работы со всеми доступными инструментами данного ресурса. Вы получите полный список всех актуальных производителей смартфонов(Apple,Samsung,Huawei и т.д) и получите доступ ко всем актуальным маркам и моделям смартфонов и, самое главное, каждый смартфон можете тестировать как адаптивную вёрстку, так же, для каждого, сможете активировать **реальный эмулятор** 
При необходимости, после завершения тестового периода вы можете купить лицензию на использование за $9.99

Comment: Работает! Отображение идентично "натуральному" iPhone, спасибо большое!

Comment: в сервисе нет выбора браузера

Answer (score 2):

Лучший способ проверки приложений и сайтов для iPhone/iPad - это Xcode, в котором можно запустить нативный iOS. Вот только Xcode доступен только для Mac.

Для Windows я бы посоветовал использовать [browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com). Там есть бесплатный пробный период.

Comment: `Вот только Xcode доступен только для Mac` - в том и проблема...

Answer (score 2):

это не ответ на вопрос, но вариант как использовать ранее полученный ответ уважаемого Vadizar, с подтверждением его правильности и описание замеченных особенностей по теме проверки верстки. может кого предостережет от безусловного доверия эмуляторам. ибо по данной в принятом ранее ответе ссылке на сайте и на нескольких найденных в сети других происходит не полная эмуляция даже после регистрации. известная на одном из сайтов проблема с версткой проявлялась только на реальных телефонах, но ни на одном из найденных сайтов с эмуляторами, включая режимы эмуляции браузеров, в том числе самого safiri. поскольку ранее был ответ что самое лучшее это использование xcode под macOS, и об этом писали во многих местах, но автор вопроса не может использовать реальный компьютер, предлагаю на виртуалку поставить macOS, а в ней использовать xcode. это реально работает и я так и сделал. в сети много описаний как установить макос на виртуальную машину, в основном повторяющих друг друга, в том числе уже готовые образы. а в xcode запускается simulator (спасибо уважаемому @nörbörnën за помощь, только благодаря этому я смог воспользоваться этим чудесным инструментом, а так же за поддержку), чего не было найдено во многих описаниях. и только так проявилась упомянутая проблема с версткой. а значит ответ по использованию xcode в macOS самый правильный. задавшему вопрос наверное это уже не нужно, но может пригодиться тем, кто как ранее автор и я искали ответ. сообщение написано не ради бонусов. и пусть я и получил минус в начале, когда кратко написал что можно заменить мак виртуалкой, но благодаря дополнению nörbörnën (в связи с этим минусом) получен реальный ответ и теперь я знаю как использовать еще один незаменимый инструмент, а сегодня и проблема уже решена. и каждый нашедший эту переписку получит ответ благодаря общей работе сообщества. спасибо всем.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну, установка macOs на виртуалку и просмотр сайтов через xcode simulator - вполне нормальный ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @Эникейщик, почему не ответ, если автор прав...???

Comment: @Air Потому что 19 часов назад ответ состоял из полутора строк.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не обратил внимания...